# Why does background worker require a Thread.Sleep() in it's DoWork event handler?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I've recently started to learn about async-await, and I built a simple app to practice with, now I want to run a for loop, and then in each loop, I want to append the current `i` of the loop to my `textbox.Text`, and I want it to run asynchronously

I couldn't directly run an async method, because it would complain that the control is being changed by a different thread than the main thread, so I found out that I have to use the `BackgroundWorker` class, but in the `DoWork` event handler of this BgWorker, I must use `thread.sleep()` to make it run asynchronously so my UI remains responsive while the for loop is running, and if I remove the `thread.sleep()`, the UI will freeze for a few seconds, and then it writes out the whole thing at once, what if I don't want that `thread.sleep()`? why is it required? how is it working? can I make it run asynchronously but without `thread.sleep()`?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100); // Why is this required in order to run asynchronously
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text += e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't have the `ThreadSleep`, then `ReportProgress` is being called as fast as possible, which means that the UI thread is being asked to update that textbox as fast as it can, which means that it's not going to have time to do anything else! Ideally when reporting progress, don't do it more often than once every few hundred ms -- there's no point, the user can't see things which change that fast, and the UI spends all of its time updating the progress, only to change it again shortly afterwards

Comment: Of course you can use `async` in Winforms, and there is usually no need to go back to the ancient `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: "why is it required? how is it working?" It's required because apparently you're not doing any significant useful work in your worker. If/When you replace that with *some useful work that takes significant time itself*, it will not be necessary.

Comment: @KlausGütter You mean there's another way to update the controls asynchronously, without using `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: Yes. Make your click handler `async void button1_Click(...)` and use `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: Note that if you want to do CPU-bound work in a background thread, you'll need `Task.Run`. If you want to report progress, you'll need `Progress<T>/IProgress<T>`

Comment: @KlausGütter But I can't directly change my `textbox.text`, it'll throw this exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`  I'm setting the textbox's text wrapped in a `Task.Run()`

Comment: Just do not wrap it into `Task.Run()`. Or, if you really need to, use `control.Invoke`.

Comment: @canton7 You're right, I actually used it before, but I didn't add `thread.sleep` and I didn't know why it's not asynchronous, that way is better than using `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: @KlausGütter Wait, it's actually working :s then why are those `IProgress` and `BackgroundWorker` even made for, your method is working fine! Thanks

Comment: Note BackgroundWorker came long before Task.Run, and sometimes you don't have direct access to a control, but still want to report progress on the main thread (e.g. your code might be in a library which could run on WinForms or WPF or anything else!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the call to `Thread.Sleep(100)`, the UI thread can't respond to your input because it's constantly busy updating the UI.

The Worker thread will start and call `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i)` immediately. Which will invoke the UI thread to update the textbox and repaint the dialog. When this is done, it will basically immediately call `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i)` again and to the exact same thing.

This means that the UI thread, instead of checking for events from user input, is constantly updating the textbox and repainting the dialog.